# Learning SQL: Need help Using HAVING to get the MIN result from an aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, min, having

was hoping to get some help. New to SQL and trying to keep my head on straight.

I've been given this assignment:

"Using HAVING, determine whose Direct Reports have the lowest Avg Salary."

My logic was to make a join on a derived table that would calculate the AVG salary of the crew for each Manager that had direct reports. This result would then get filtered to the MIN value by a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT Flash.firstname, Flash.lastname, Wally.AVGSalary, 
       Wally.[Direct Reports] FROM CrewMembers Flash
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT Barry.crewMemberId, AVG(Zoom.salary) AS 'AVGSalary', COUNT(Zoom.firstname) AS 'Direct Reports' 
                    FROM CrewMembers Barry
            JOIN CrewMembers Zoom 
                           ON Zoom.managerId = Barry.crewMemberId
        GROUP BY Barry.crewMemberId 
    ) 
    AS Wally ON Wally.crewMemberId = Flash.crewMemberId

GROUP BY Flash.firstname, Flash.lastname, Wally.AVGSalary, Wally.[Direct Reports]

HAVING MIN(Wally.AVGSalary) in (Wally.AVGSalary)

ORDER BY Wally.AVGSalary asc
```

I'm getting this result:

```
firstname   lastname    AVGSalary   Direct Reports
Mike        Patton      33666.500000    2
Kurt        Corgan      37300.000000    2
Amber       Bruckner    45851.666666    3
Doug        Adams       86250.000000    2
Montgomery  Scott       92500.000000    2
James       Kirk        132666.750000   3
```

I'm stumped. I need it to give me JUST the row with the minimum value and it's giving me every value. I've stared at this and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I know, from looking at threads online, that using TOP is a way to filter items, but that hasn't been introduced yet and I'd like to stay within the parameters that have been established in the course so far.

Any critique of what I've written or any help would be awesome. Like I said, I'm new and just trying to keep up.

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need another subquery (if you dont want use top/window function/etc):

```
select Flash.firstname,
    Flash.lastname,
    Wally.AVGSalary,
    Wally.[Direct Reports]
from CrewMembers Flash
join (
    select Barry.crewMemberId,
        AVG(Zoom.salary) as 'AVGSalary',
        COUNT(Zoom.firstname) as 'Direct Reports'
    from CrewMembers Barry
    join CrewMembers Zoom on Zoom.managerId = Barry.crewMemberId
    group by Barry.crewMemberId
    having avg(Zoom.salary) = (
            select min(salary)
            from (
                select AVG(Zoom.salary) as salary
                from CrewMembers Barry
                join CrewMembers Zoom on Zoom.managerId = Barry.crewMemberId
                group by Barry.crewMemberId
                ) t
            )
    ) as Wally on Wally.crewMemberId = Flash.crewMemberId
```

You can use `top`:

```
select top 1 Flash.firstname,
    Flash.lastname,
    Wally.AVGSalary,
    Wally.[Direct Reports]
from CrewMembers Flash
join (
    select Barry.crewMemberId,
        AVG(Zoom.salary) as 'AVGSalary',
        COUNT(Zoom.firstname) as 'Direct Reports'
    from CrewMembers Barry
    join CrewMembers Zoom on Zoom.managerId = Barry.crewMemberId
    group by Barry.crewMemberId
    ) as Wally on Wally.crewMemberId = Flash.crewMemberId
order by Wally.AVGSalary
```

Another way is using window function `rank`:

```
select Flash.firstname,
    Flash.lastname,
    Wally.AVGSalary,
    Wally.[Direct Reports]
from CrewMembers Flash
join (
    select Barry.crewMemberId,
        AVG(Zoom.salary) as 'AVGSalary',
        COUNT(Zoom.firstname) as 'Direct Reports',
        rank() over (order by AVG(Zoom.salary)) as rnk
    from CrewMembers Barry
    join CrewMembers Zoom on Zoom.managerId = Barry.crewMemberId
    group by Barry.crewMemberId
    ) as Wally on Wally.crewMemberId = Flash.crewMemberId
where Wally.rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Hey GurV, I had seen TOP online, but that hasn't been introduced in the course yet.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using WHERE. Apparently, I have to use HAVING to get the result. It seems like it's making the question purposefully ridiculous.

Comment: @ROKPLYR - Just now updated the answer with subquery in having (see the first)

Comment: That solved it! Thanks for taking the time to lay this out. I've been stuck on this for two days...

Comment: @ROKPLYR - Glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HAVING` with equals to instead of `IN` so something like:

`HAVING Wally.AVGSalary = MIN(Wally.AVGSalary)`

In your case with `IN` it will return all rows and you want only the want with salary equals to lowest one.

Comment: HAVING Wally.AVGSalary = MIN(Wally.AVGSalary) is giving me the same result

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select crewMemberId, avgSalary
From (Select s.crewMemberId, 
         AVG(d.salary) avgSalary
      From CrewMembers d join CrewMembers s 
         on s.crewMemberId = d.managerId 
      group by s.crewMemberId) x
Where avgSalary = 
   (Select Min(avgSalary) 
    from (Select s.crewMemberId, 
             AVG(d.salary) avgSalary
          From CrewMembers d join CrewMembers s 
              on s.crewMemberId = d.managerId 
          group by s.crewMemberId)x)
```

-- Using sample data in a temp table variable:

```
declare @e table(crewmemberId int primary key not null, 
              managerId int null, salary decimal)
Insert @e(crewmemberId, managerId, salary)
values (1, null, 23), 
       (2,1,45), (3,1,33), (4,1,80), 
       (5,2,14), (6,2,8), (7,2,12),
       (8,3,11), (9,3,5), (10,3,2), 
       (11,4,51), (12,4,38), (13,4,17) 

Select crewMemberId, avgSalary
From (Select s.crewMemberId, 
         AVG(d.salary) avgSalary
      From @e d join @e s 
         on s.crewMemberId = d.managerId 
      group by s.crewMemberId) x
Where avgSalary = 
   (Select Min(avgSalary)
    From (Select s.crewMemberId, 
            AVG(d.salary) avgSalary
          From @e d join @e s 
             on s.crewMemberId = d.managerId 
          group by s.crewMemberId)x)
```

this gives crewmemberId = 3, Avg Salary = 6.0000;

It has the advantage of producing multiple results if direct hires of two or more Managers have the same avg salaries.